# Рекурсивно получить список всех детей в дереве (List child)

Tags: c#, unity3d, рекурсия

Есть объект :

```
public class mapObject {
    public List<Vector3> ListGeometry;
    public int geometry_type;
    public string key;
    public int layer_number;
    public string name;
    public Sprite icon;
    public string url_texture;
    public string url_prtefab;
    public List<mapObject> childMapObject=null;
}
```

Как мне с помощью рекурсии получить список всех детей объекта 'childMapObject'.

Я делаю так :

```
             List<mapObject> temoMObj= new List<mapObject>();
 ...
             List<mapObject> ListChildren(List<mapObject> choiceListMapObj) {
                 if(temoMObj.Count>0) { } else { temoMObj = new List<mapObject>(); } 
                 for(int i=0;i<choiceListMapObj.Count;i++) {
                     for(int j=0;j<choiceListMapObj[i].childMapObject.Count;j++) {
                            temoMObj.Add(choiceListMapObj[i].childMapObject[j]);
                            if(choiceListMapObj[i].childMapObject[j].childMapObject!=null) {
                                ListChildren(choiceListMapObj[i].childMapObject[j].childMapObject);
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 return temoMObj;
             }
 ...
```

Но это вызывает ошибку:

`StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.`

> Вложений может быть три и больше(обычно максимум 5 вложений).

Comment: а зачем вам все это если всю эту информацию можно хранить в иерархии сцены? Объясните что вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: @KingPeas мне надо получить mapObject и его детей. Сформировать новый List<mapObject> ..... чтоб вывести его в своём виджете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла [ссылка](https://blog.zwezdin.com/2009/linq-recurse/) .

Мой код :

```
public class mapObject
{
    public bool toggle{ get; set; }
    public bool toggle_pref{ get; set; }
    public bool toggle_tex{ get; set; }
    public int iddb{ get; set; }
    public List<Vector3> ListGeometry{ get; set; }
    public int geometry_type{ get; set; }
    public string key{ get; set; }
    public int layer_number{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public Sprite icon{ get; set; }
    public string url_texture{ get; set; }
    // public string url_prtefab;
    public float mObj_flobjectLandingFrequencyScale{ get; set; }
    public float mObj_brushsize{ get; set; }
    public int id_method{ get; set; }
    public List <mapObject> childMapObject { get; set; }
}


    public List<mapObject> GetAllNodes(mapObject data)
    {
        var result = new List<mapObject>();

        if (data != null && data.childMapObject != null)
        {

            foreach (var item in data.childMapObject)
            {
                result.Add(item);
                result.AddRange(GetAllNodes(item));
            }
        }
        result.Add(data);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Вложений может быть бесконечно много.

Вложений не может быть бесконечно много, в противном случае это вызовет stack overflow.

---

У Вас в данных получился замкнутый цикл родителей-детей. Поэтому Ваша функция никогда не закончится, а будет уходить все глубже и глубже, пока не поизойдет stack overflow.

---

Не говоря уже о том, что Вы пропускаете каждый второй уровень объектов.

---

А вот это

```
if(temoMObj.Count>0) { } else { temoMObj = new List<mapObject>(); }
```

мой мозг отказывается понимать.

Comment: Выражение с if для того чтоб temoMObj каждый раз когда происходит рекурсия, не обнулялся. temoMObj , если заметили это ещё и глобальный список

Comment: Можете в ответе предложить свой вариант рекурсии?

Comment: Как мне проверить что детей больше нет ? и прервать в этом случае мою функцию. Вернув список объектов

Comment: Поправил вопрос, относительно ваших замечаний

Answer (score 1):

Делайте проще и жить будет легче).
Элементарная рекурсия

```
public mapObject GetMap(GameObject parent)
{
  mapObject myMap = CreateMapFromObject(parent);
  Transform trans = myMap.transform;
  List<mapObject> childs = new List<mapObject>();
  for(int i=0; i < trans.ChildCount; i++)
  {
    childs.Add(GetMap(trans.GetChild(i)));
  }
  myMap.childMapObject = childs;
}
```

Набирал по памяти, на работе Unity нет, так что могут быть ошибки, но смысл такой. `CreateMapFromObject`- метод который заполняет ваш мэп данными с объекта не просматривая детей.

Comment: Спасибо позже проверю и если подойдет ,отмечу как правильно

Comment: Существенно изменили то что я делал. GameObject не совсем годен для  : EditorWindow. Попробую переделать ваш вариант

Comment: Функцию CreateMapFromObject(parent); можно тоже выложить?

Comment: Абсолютно не работающая функция .... Я потом перепишу ответ, когда дойдут руки до этого.

Comment: CreateMapFromObject(parent); - это должна быть ваша функция, которая на базе объекта заполняет ваш мэп данными. Я ее описать не могу, потому что не понимаю что в вашем мэпе за данные хранятся и откуда они должны извлекаться)... Про EditorWindow не очень понял замечание... как по вашему иерархия сцены сделана?

Comment: (Про EditorWindow не очень понял замечание) Мне на до использовать и передавать + обрабатывать мой класс mapObject. GameObject это другая сущность.(GameObject не совсем годен для : EditorWindow.) Это я не то  написал. Глупость ляпнул, не подумав